# Trying to acsess different parts of a json array and use in a HTML table

Tags: jquery, json

Hi i´m trying to setup a webpage to get some sport results from an API and then put that page as an overlay in a video stream showing the finnish of that sport event.

I use CURL to get the array, store it in $response i can see that i get the answer.
Then i try to build the page but i dont get the hang of how i access different parts of the JSON.

```
<body>
    <h1>Sprint DM Sörmland 2020</h1>
    <p>Senaste Resultat</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Birthday</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">
        
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    var myArray = [
        { "status": "OK", "passings" : [{"passtime": "16:20:29",
                    "runnerName": "Andrew Blyth",
                    "class": "H45",
                    "control": 1000,
                    "controlName" : "",
                    "time": "111:26" },{"passtime": "16:12:15",
                    "runnerName": "Erica Blyth",
                    "class": "D21",
                    "control": 1000,
                    "controlName" : "",
                    "time": "108:09" },{"passtime": "15:59:54",
                    "runnerName": "Björn Normark",
                    "class": "H21",
                    "control": 1000,
                    "controlName" : "",
                    "time": "felst." }], "hash": "4d3d4a2d9d3fefe360568918ed63cc99"}    ]
    
    buildTable(myArray)



    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].status}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].runnerName}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].class}</td>
                      </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }

</script>
```

I´m sorry if this is totally newbie questions, but last time i was into some webpage development .css just had became a thing!

Regards
/Sebbe

Comment: Eg `myArray[0].passings` will give you the array of runner objects

Comment: You are a Hero! Thank you i´ve been scrolling a bunch of pages that try to explain to me how json and jquery works together but you little myArray was the lightbulb i needed!